# Lie groups over fields of finite characteristic

Tags: field-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, finite-fields, positive-characteristic

Does anyone have any good references on Lie groups over fields of finite characteristic? I am trying to find something comprehensive that shows what fails and what succeeds in comparison to Lie theory with the usual fields like $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ when using fields of finite characteristic.

Comment: How do you even define a smooth structure if the field is not one of the usual ones you listed?

Comment: By "Lie group" I suppose the OP means [group of Lie type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type).

Comment: @freakish: That's what I assumed on first sight as well, but then I realized OP does not actually specify finite fields, but just fields of positive characteristic, which could also mean a local field like $\mathbb F_p((t))$ over which one can at least do some "classical" Lie theory (cf. Bourbaki, Lie Groups and Algebras, ch. III §§1-4). Ty Jensen, please clarify.